# Pass Google OpenID Session from one page to another

Tags: php, session, openid

I'm implementing a google openid script on my site. There are 3 main components:

index.php, where the login link is:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['UNAME']) && !(empty($_SESSION['UNAME']))){
echo '<a href="logout.php"><b><u>Logout</u></b></a><br/><br/>';
echo "Name:-".$_SESSION['UNAME']."<br/><br/>";
echo "Email:-".$_SESSION['UEMAIL'];
}else{
echo '<a href="login_process.php">Login With Gmail</a>';
}
?>
```

login_process.php, which logs in the user:

```
<?php
include('inc/lightopenid.php');
$callback_website_url='http://mysite/google_login/google_landing.php';
googleAuthenticate($callback_website_url);

function googleAuthenticate($callback_website_url) {
    $openid = new lightopenid;
    $openid->identity = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id';
    $openid->returnUrl = $callback_website_url;
    $endpoint = $openid->discover('https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id');
    $fields ='?openid.ns=' . urlencode('http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0') .
        '&openid.return_to=' . urlencode($openid->returnUrl) .
        '&openid.claimed_id=' . 
urlencode('http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select') .
        '&openid.identity=' . 
urlencode('http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select') .
        '&openid.mode=' . urlencode('checkid_setup') .
        '&openid.ns.ax=' . urlencode('http://openid.net/srv/ax/1.0') .
        '&openid.ax.mode=' . urlencode('fetch_request') .
        '&openid.ax.required=' . urlencode('email,firstname,lastname') .
        '&openid.ax.type.firstname=' .  
urlencode('http://axschema.org/namePerson/first') .
        '&openid.ax.type.lastname=' .   
urlencode('http://axschema.org/namePerson/last') .
        '&openid.ax.type.email=' . urlencode('http://axschema.org/contact/email');
        header('location:'.$endpoint . $fields);            
}
?>
```

google_landing.php, which redirects to the landing page:

```
<?php
session_start();
include('inc/dbConnect.inc.php');
if (!empty($_GET['openid_ext1_value_firstname']) && !empty($_GET['openid_ext1_value_lastname']) && !empty($_GET['openid_ext1_value_email'])) {    
    $username = $_GET['openid_ext1_value_firstname'] . $_GET['openid_ext1_value_lastname'];
    $email = $_GET['openid_ext1_value_email'];

    $uname=$_GET['openid_ext1_value_firstname'].' '.$_GET['openid_ext1_value_lastname'];
    $email=$_GET['openid_ext1_value_email'];

    $checkUserSql="select * from google_login where email= '$email'";
    $checkUserRes=mysql_query($checkUserSql);
    $checkUserCount=mysql_num_rows($checkUserRes);

    if($checkUserCount == 0){
        $sql="insert into google_login(name,email,inserted_on) values('$uname','$email',now())";
        mysql_query($sql);
    }
    $_SESSION['UNAME']=$_GET['openid_ext1_value_firstname'].' '.$_GET['openid_ext1_value_lastname'];
    $_SESSION['UEMAIL']=$_GET['openid_ext1_value_email'];
    }
header('location:../index.php');

?>
```

Problem is, once the user gets logged in and tries to move from the index page to any other page, he is faced with a "Login with Gmail" link again, instead of the session being passed across between pages and then showing him as logged in with his login details.

Can you help? Thanks.

edit: this is the page i want to move to from the index:

bible-query:

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>
<html>
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/mybq-images/BQ.png">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle-a.css">
<title>BQuotes CMS: Random Bible Verse</title>
</head>
<body class='left'>

<div class='table1'>
<table width='100%'>
<col width='100'>
<col width='100'>
<col width='100'> 
<tr><td><b>BQuotes Random Bible Verse</b></td></tr>
<tr><td>
<?php
session_start();
if ($_SESSION['timeout'] + 10 * 60 < time()) {
// session timed out
session_destroy();
//header("Location: mybq-logout.php");
  }

$_SESSION['timeout'] = time();  


// regular login begin
if (!(isset($_SESSION['myusername']) && $_SESSION['myusername'] != '')) {

echo "<div class='right'><a href='mybq-login.php'>Login </a></div>";

                                                                        }

else                     {    

echo "<div class='right'><a href='mybq-logout.php'>Logout </a>" . $_SESSION['myusername'] . "</div>";
// regular login end
                         }

?>
</td>

</tr>



<tr>
<td width='180'>
<div class='center2'>

<?php

$id = $_GET['id']; //get initial query from index

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db;charset=utf8', 'username', 'password');

$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT id,book,cap,verse,line FROM bible_kjv where id = ?');
if($stmt->execute(array($id))){
    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        echo "<p>", ($row['book']), " ", ($row['cap']), " ", ($row['verse'])," <br>";
        echo "<p>", ($row['line']), "<br>", "<br>";
    }
}

?>
</div>
</td></tr>

<!--bible query new section begins-->
<tr><td>
<div class='center2'>
<?php

foreach($db->query("SELECT id,book,cap,verse,line FROM bible_kjv ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1") as $row) {
   echo "<a href='bible-query.php?id=$row[id]'>New Verse</a> ";
}

?>

<!--bible query new section ends-->



<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button">Tweet</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>
<br>
</div>
</td></tr>

<tr><td>
<div class='center2'>
<a href = "index.php">CMS Index</a>
</div>
</td></tr>

<tr><td colspan='2'>
<div class='center2'>
<form method="get" action="bible-search.php">
<label>Search BIBLE For: </label><input type="text" name="query" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" />
<input type="reset" value="Reset" />
</form>
<div class='tagtext'>E.G.: Deuteronomy 28, Deuteronomy 28 2, the Lord shall make thee the head</div>
</div>
</td></tr>

</table>

 </body> </html>
<?php ob_flush(); ?>
```

Comment: can you show the pther page also where user want move ?

Comment: hi echo_Me, please see the edit in the main section