# Can't pass a session variable logging in with OpenID?

Tags: php, session, authentication, google-openid

I tried running this code which creates a SESSION variable for the Google email but for some reason the `$_SESSION['email']` does not want to store the data. I run the code and the only output I get after signing in with google is

```
hello world 1

hello world 2

<?php

session_start(); 

require 'openid.php';
$openid = new LightOpenID('http://www.splunk.com'); 

if (!$openid->mode) 
{
   $openid->identity = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id';
   $openid->required = array('contact/email');
   header('Location: ' . $openid->authUrl());
} 
else 
{
   if ($openid->validate()) 
   {
      //echo "Hello World!";
      $attributes = $openid->getAttributes();
      $google_email = $attributes['contact/email'];
      $_SESSION['email'] = $google_email;
      echo $google_email."<br />";
      echo "<pre>" . print_r($_GET, true) . "</pre>";
      echo $_GET['contact_email'];
      header("Location: " . google_login.php);

   }
   else
   {
      echo '<p>hello world 1</p>';
      echo "<p>". $_SESSION['email']. "</p>";
      echo '<p>hello world 2</p>';
   }
}

?>
```

I modified the above example with the google example from the [`LightOpenID` site](https://gitorious.org/lightopenid) but now it doesn't validate for some reason.

```
<?php
# Logging in with Google accounts requires setting special identity, so this example shows how to do it.
require 'openid.php';
try 
{
    # Change 'localhost' to your domain name.
    $openid = new LightOpenID('http://www.splunk.com');
    if(!$openid->mode) 
    {
        if(isset($_GET['login'])) 
        {
            $openid->identity = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id'; 
            $openid->required = array('contact/email');
            header('Location: ' . $openid->authUrl());
        }
?>
<form action="?login" method="post">
    <button>Login with Google</button>
</form>
<?php
    } 
    else if($openid->mode == 'cancel') 
    {
        echo 'User has canceled authentication!';
    } 
    else 
    {
        $attributes = $openid->getAttributes();
        $google_email = $attributes['contact/email'];
        echo $google_email;
        echo 'User ' . ($openid->validate() ? $openid->identity . ' has ' : 'has not ') . 'logged in.';
    }
} catch(ErrorException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: According to your code, `$openid->validate()` returns `false` so that session variable is never set.

Comment: I see, can you help me find a work around that problem? I'm not sure how to get the `$openid->validate()` to return true.

Comment: You should check the documentation of the `openid` script you are using or search here on how to get openid to work / validate.

Comment: I've looked around this site already and no luck, that's where I got this from.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20691101/pass-google-openid-session-from-one-page-to-another?rq=1   With no answer??? I don't know what it's so hard to make this work with google.

Comment: You should download the source from https://gitorious.org/lightopenid and look at the examples.

Comment: Tried it already,see my question from another thread, I got the code for this thread from that answer (which doesn't even work). Maybe you can answer this one. It's a modified version of their google example trying to accept form input https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22369429/openid-login-with-google-and-grabbing-the-user-form-input-with-a-session-variabl#comment34003992_22369570

Comment: @jeroen See my code above, now it doesn't validate although I changed the google openid example just a tiny amount.